# SQL to also get rest of sums based on highest colum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL below with an issue i am trying to resolve. I basically need to get the sum of the acreage once the highest parcel_status (3) is detected to also be include in SumofTonnage.

IE once parcel_status is 3 get the SumofTonnage for parcels that have status from 0, 1, 2

```
SELECT 
    CROP_CLASS As Closed,
    SUM(tonnage_adjusted) AS SumofTonnage,
    SUM(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage
FROM 
    CaneParcel
INNER JOIN  
    DeliveryTons ON CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id 
WHERE
    parcel_status = '3'
GROUP BY 
   CROP_CLASS
ORDER BY 
   CROP_CLASS ASC
```

DeliveryTons

```
id | parcel_id | tonnage_adjusted | parcel_status 

1  |  302-234 | 34.56 | 1
2  |  302-234 | 14.56 | 2
3  |  302-234 | 17.56 | 3
4  |  302-235 |  8.56 | 1
5  |  302-236 | 11.56 | 1
6  |  302-236 | 18.56 | 3
```

CaneParcel

```
id | ACREAGE | FIELD_ID | CROP_CLASS

1 | 1.34 | 302-234 | RATOON 

2 | 1.64 | 302-235 | RATOON 

3 | 1.54 | 302-236| PLANTCANE
```

OUT PUT:

```
Closed | SumofTonnage | SumofAcreage

RATOON     66.68 | 2.98
PLANTCANE  30.12 | 1.54
```

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a question similar to this yesterday, but in any case you should give us some sample data to work with here.

Comment: The sql basically picks up sum of tonnages when parcel_status is 1,2,3. However i want that when it detects 3 to include the tonnages of status 1 and 2 and 3 in the SUM

Comment: What happens when the `parcel_status` of value 3 is not detected?  Then how do we compute the sum in that case?

Comment: well i have 3 queries so far on a report. one is for status 1 one for status 2 and one for status 3 but i only need the sums of all parcels once the highest status (3) is detected. IE a parcel can have more than one status so for 1 and this same query with the rule of value  1 is used.     for 2 this same query is used. only for status 3 i would like to get the sum of all same parcel_ids with  1 , 2 and 3 included.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to first aggregate adjusted tonnage in the `DeliveryTons` table by parcel, but only if that parcel has status 3 appearing.  The CTE below does this, and parcels not having status 3 will not appear in the result set of that CTE.

Then, you want to join this result to the `CaneParcel` table, and again aggregate over crop class.  This time, we take the sum of the effective adjusted tonnage as well as the acreage.  I said "effective" tonnage, because some parcels will effectively have zero tonnage if they did not meet the criteria.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT parcel_id, SUM(tonnage_adjusted) AS tonnage_adjusted_sum
    FROM DeliveryTons
    GROUP BY parcel_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN parcel_status = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
)

SELECT cp.CROP_CLASS As Closed,
       SUM(ISNULL(dt.tonnage_adjusted_sum, 0)) AS SumofTonnage,
       SUM(cp.ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage
FROM CaneParcel cp
LEFT JOIN cte dt
    ON cp.FIELD_ID = dt.parcel_id
GROUP BY cp.CROP_CLASS
ORDER BY cp.CROP_CLASS ASC
```

Contrary to what you seem to be saying in the comments, this query does produce your expected output:

## Rextester

I used MySQL for the demo, but the logic would be no different in SQL Server.

Comment: This seems to work. I will try to validate it. Once there are more than one parcels with the same id but one has 3 as  parcel_status it should pick up the sum of tonnage for all eg. (ID-345, tonnage-45, status-1) (ID-345,tonnage-5,status-2) ( ID-345,tonnage-13,status-3) should give tonnage sum = 63

Comment: Okay the query works however there is an issue because the acreage is also added and it should not be. What i need is the SUM of Average. IE. something like SUM(AVG(Acreage) as SumofAcreage, but this throws an error. I use average because the acreage does not change per parcel ID but i do need the Sum of the Average.

Comment: @ivias Without seeing your data, I'm afraid I don't follow you.  If you just want the sum of the average, we can put my query into a CTE and than take the sum.  What do you have in mind here?

Comment: Yes I would something like the following:  SUM(AVG(ACREAGE)) AS SumofAcreage. IE i would like the average because that will give me back the actual acreage and then i need the sum of those values

Comment: Update your question with minimal sample data, and please also tell us what version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Please show the expected output.  I have to sleep soon.

Comment: Would this modifcation give me the results i want? SUM(ACREAGE)/AVG(ACREAGE) AS SumofAcreage?

Comment: I updated my answer and I think I got it right now.  This illustrates the importance of giving sample data and output when asking a complex SQL question.

Comment: okay. however i got 2 different values from SumofTonnage fromthe 2 different queries when i was only expecting the sumofAcreage to change

Comment: I am getting PLANTCANE 68598.2469, RATOON 152772.6230 for first query for SumofTonnage and geting PLANTCANE 28152.5912, RATOON 69218.8084

Comment: This last query seems to be giving me for all parcel statuses and not just taking into consideration only summing 1,2 and 3 when the status is 3

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I appreciate your help. Ill double check